# Bootstrap-carousel lazy loader

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have got the bootstrap carousel working on my web page and i want it to lazy load.
I have found this piece of code on the internet:

```
$("#myCarousel").bind("slid", function(){
    $img = $(".active img", this);
    $img.attr("src", $img.data('lazy-load-src'));
});
```

This causes the carousel to "load" the current image when the next button (or prev) button is clicked. I want it to load not the current image but the image after that, and the image in front of the current image, so that i still have the nice sliding animation. And not a loading image.

So my question is how do I set the lazy-load-src to src of the previous image and of the next image when the next button is clicked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options, depending on the precision you need, but you should keep the `lazy-load-src` to their own `img` tags.

You can use selectors, put in `data-` attributes and use that to select your *next* image to load. But this is messy.

I think your best shot is using the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method on your items, so that on `slid` you load the next image. Something like :

```js
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function() {
    var $nextImage = $('.active.item', this).next('.item').find('img');
    $nextImage.attr('src', $nextImage.data('lazy-load-src'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've updated Sherbrows answer a bit to support Bootstrap v3 and a random start index. I'm using a page of thumbnails. When a user clicks a thumb, the carousel should start at that index.

**Show the carousel**

```
function showGallery(startIndex) {
    //Load first and second image
    var imageElement = $('#fullscreengallery .item:nth-child(' + (startIndex + 1) + ') img');
    imageElement.attr('src', imageElement.attr('data-lazy-load-src'));
    imageElement = $('#fullscreengallery .item:nth-child(' + (startIndex + 2) + ') img');
    imageElement.attr('src', imageElement.attr('data-lazy-load-src'));
    //Init carousel
    $('#fullscreengallery').carousel(startIndex);
    //Show carousel
    $('#fullscreengallery').removeClass('hidden');
};
```

**Do lazy loading**

```
$('#fullscreengallery').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    //Lazy load
    var nextImage = $('.active.item', this).next('.item').find('img');
    //If no next, select first
    if(nextImage.length === 0){
        nextImage = $('#fullscreengallery .item:nth-child(1) img');
    }
    //Set the source if it hasn't been set already
    if (!nextImage.attr('src')) {
        nextImage.attr('src', nextImage.attr('data-lazy-load-src'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I took Arnoud Sietsema's answer a step further. The images in your carousel could have loading gifs to begin with. Then...

Show the carousel

```
function showGallery(startIndex) {
    //Load first, second and last image
    var imageElement = $('#fullscreengallery .item:nth-child(' + (startIndex + 1) + ') img');
    imageElement.attr('src', imageElement.attr('data-lazy-load-src'));
    imageElement.attr('data-loaded', '1');

    imageElement = $('#fullscreengallery .item:nth-child(' + (startIndex + 2) + ') img');
    imageElement.attr('src', imageElement.attr('data-lazy-load-src'));
    imageElement.attr('data-loaded', '1');

    imageElement = $('#myCarousel .item:last img');
    imageElement.attr('src', imageElement.attr('data-src'));
    imageElement.attr('data-loaded', '1');

    //Init carousel
    $('#fullscreengallery').carousel(startIndex);
    //Show carousel
    $('#fullscreengallery').removeClass('hidden');
};
```

Do lazy loading

```
$('#fullscreengallery').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    //Lazy load
    var nextImage = $('.active.item', this).next('.item').find('img');
    //If no next, select first
    if(nextImage.length === 0){
        nextImage = $('#fullscreengallery .item:nth-child(1) img');
    }

    //Set the source if it hasn't been set already
    if (nextImage.attr('data-loaded') == '0') {
        var $downloadingImage = $("<img>");
        $downloadingImage.load(function(){
        nextImage.attr("src", $(this).attr("src")); 
            nextImage.attr('data-loaded', '1');
        });
        $downloadingImage.attr("src", nextImage.attr('data-src'));
    }

    var prevImage = $('.active.item', this).prev('.item').find('img');
    //If none, select last
    if(prevImage.length === 0){
        prevImage = $('#myCarousel .item:last img');
    }
    //Set the source if it hasn't been set already
    if (prevImage.attr('data-loaded') == '0') {
        var $downloadingImage = $("<img>");
        $downloadingImage.load(function(){
            prevImage.attr("src", $(this).attr("src")); 
            prevImage.attr('data-loaded', '1');
        });
        $downloadingImage.attr("src", prevImage.attr('data-src'));
    }


});
```

The difference is that, when trying to load the next slide, it's first loaded 'under the hood', and, only when loaded, inserted into the carousel. As a result, the loading image is shown until the image is fully loaded.

Also, the carousel can now be moved in both directions.